# Permission error - cannot delete uploaded files from FTP

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions

I have found several posts asking similar questions however this situation is different.  In my upload class I'm creating a directory from a user's id with `mkdir`, then calling `move_uploaded_file` to move the tmp file to `/uploads/id/file` after performing several other checks.  My problem is that I can't seem to delete the file once it's been uploaded by PHP to the directory created by `mkdir`.  I can however delete files uploaded to the root of `/uploads` as well as directories created in `/uploads`.  For testing purposes, I've used permission `0777` with `mkdir` and I'm calling `chmod` on the file with `0777` after calling `move_uploaded_file`.

I thought this was because PHP uses the linux user that starts apache httpd to upload files, and I was signing into FTP with a different user, however I am still able to delete files uploaded to the root of `/uploads` regardless of the user.  I've made sure `/uploads` is owned by the same user that starts apache but I'm still not having any luck.  Any help at all would be appreciated.